# Can the button padding be adjusted in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, button, mobile, padding

Please see the buttons on this page: http://rchobbystream.com/main.html

Is it possible to eliminate the white space around the image in each button?  I have been looking for a while and I can not see where this is indicated in the CSS file.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the class is:

```
 .ui-btn-inner
```

If you use firebug you can see it very easily by hovering over it with the inspect button.

Your CSS override should look like this (padding changed to 0):

```
.ui-btn-inner {
    padding: 0;
}
```